# how two orderby will work together

Tags: mysql, codeigniter-3

a table with 2 column

1. 845-0
2. 784-3
3. 415-1
4. 410-2
5. 455-2

Desire table:::

1. 845-0
2. 415-1
3. 455-2
4. 410-2
5. 784-3

so here 1st column DESC, 2nd column ASC
how can i arrange a table like 2nd table from 1st table in CI mysqli ?

Comment: SELECT * FROM TABLE ORDER BY THAT_COLUMN ASC;

Comment: `...ORDER BY second_column ASC, first_column DESC;`

Comment: dear @cdm i have tried like your suggestion, but its second_column ASC works only.. :(

Comment: owooo Its ok thank you @cdm

Answer (score 0):

```
...ORDER BY second_column ASC, first_column DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use in the model code after the query and before execution.

`$this->db->order_by('column1 desc, column2 asc');`

you can change accordingly,

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->db->order_by('column1', desc');
$this->db->order_by('column2', desc');
```

**I used this and solved my problem.**